# Connecting to multiple networks simultaneously?

Tags: networking

Does connecting to multiple networks with different subnet in Ubuntu actually require some extra steps to work correctly?

I have 2 network interfaces on my computer, one is wired nic and the other is wireless USB adapter. Both of them are connected to different routers on different subnet. Before you ask

```
$ ip -4 a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    inet 10.10.1.2/24 brd 10.10.1.255 scope global eth0
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan1

$ ip -4 r
default via 10.10.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.1.2  metric 1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2  metric 2 

$ netstat -rn output
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.1.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.10.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan1
```

I can ping both of the gateway IP fine but binding a connection to the USB adapter network never work. So any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION!**

Turns out that I need to add a new routing table for the additional nic and then add routing rules for it in the table. Read more for instructions in this [link](http://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `curl`, but `wget`'s man page says:

```
   --bind-address=ADDRESS
       When making client TCP/IP connections, bind to ADDRESS on the local
       machine.  ADDRESS may be specified as a hostname or IP address.
       This option can be useful if your machine is bound to multiple IPs.
```

Specify the IP address of the nic you want to use.

Comment: I know how to bind interface :)